# How to get the element inside a div

Tags: jquery

I have a image then an anchor and then a div which contain a textarea.
How to get the id of that textarea on clicking image?

Below is my **HTML**

```
<img  src="Image/icons/preview.png" alt="Preview" id="img1" onclick="ViewHtml(this.id);" />

<a id="ancHeader">Header html</a>  

<div class="collapse">
    <textarea rows="30" cols="22" id="txtHtmlHead" class="editor"></textarea>
</div
```

I want to get the id of the textarea on image click.below is my javascript function

```
function ViewHtml(id) {
    $("#" + id).siblings('div.collapse first > textarea.editor').val();
}
```

But the above code is not working.
Can anyone help me please..?

Comment: document.getElementbyId() .. look it up

Comment: Its not exactly clear on what you are trying to achieve.  Got me confused.  One strong recommendation.  Do the tutorial at http://try.jquery.com  That was time well spent, particularly ...$(this).closest('#id of interest...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function ViewHtml(id) {
   var id = $("#" + id).siblings('div.collapse').children('textarea.editor').prop('id');
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XfuS/1/).

I'd recommend against using onClick though. Since you're using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).siblings('div.collapse').children('textarea.editor').prop('id');
});
```

Adjust the selector as necessary if you need this on more than one image.

This is all assuming that the `div` you are selecting is always relative to the image. If otherwise, you can simplify and optimize this:

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
    var id = $('.collapse > .editor').prop('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why make it hard for you?
If you have that exact same structure and just 1 occurence below will help you out

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    var textareaId = $('.collapse textarea').attr('id');
    $('.collapse textarea').val(textareaId);
});
```

Otherwise, wrap it all in a div

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="Image/icons/preview.png" alt="Preview" id="img1" />
    <a id="ancHeader">Header html</a> 
    <div class="collapse">
        <textarea rows="30" cols="22" id="txtHtmlHead" class="editor"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery

```
$('#wrapper img').on('click', function (e) {
    var textareaId = $(this).siblings('.collapse').children('textarea').attr('id');
    $('.collapse textarea').val(textareaId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$("#img1").click(function () {
    $(".collapse textarea").attr("id");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g2QKw/)

Comment: Why `.attr()`? Why not `.prop()`?

Comment: An attribute value may only be a string whereas a property can be of any type. For example, the checked property is a Boolean, the style property is an object with individual properties for each style, the size property is a number.So i used attr(id)

Comment: I believe that the `id` property of all HTML elements is a string.

Comment: If you know that the property of `id` is *always* a string, why would you use `attr()` instead of `prop()`?

Answer (score -1):

I think, it is better to use data attribute of the element.

```
<img  src="Image/icons/preview.png" alt="Preview" data-rel="txtHtmlHead1" id="img1"  class="getHtml"/>

<a id="ancHeader" >Header html</a>  

<div class="collapse">
   <textarea rows="30" cols="22" id="txtHtmlHead1" class="editor"></textarea>
</div
```

Just manage the data-rel attribute dynamic .
**txtHtmlHead1**

```
function ViewHtml(id) {

   $("#" + id).siblings('div.collapse first > textarea.editor').val();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".getHtml").bind('click',function(){
var getTextAreaId = $(this).data('rel');

 if(getTextAreaId != undefined){

    alert($("#"+getTextAreaId).val()); // your output
    }


});
})
```

I just replaced your **ViewHtml** by binding it with Click event.